# WPF Are NotifyPropertyChangeds marshalled to the dispatcher?

Tags: wpf, inotifypropertychanged, dispatcher

If I update a property that throws a NotifyPropertyChanged on a thread other than the bound control's dispatcher is the update forcibly marshalled to this dispatcher?

```
BackgrounWorker.Run() => { blah.Blahness = 2; // notifies property changed on BW, is this marshalled to the dispatcher? }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the `PropertyChanged` event is automatically marshalled to the UI dispatcher, so you don't need to use `Invoke` to marshall it explicitly.

Note that it is only true for change notifications on scalar properties (i.e. `PropertyChanged` event). Collection change notifications (`INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event) don't work that way, they must be raised on the UI thread manually. I wrote a class that does it automatically, you can find it [here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/04/17/wpf-binding-to-an-asynchronous-collection/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Thomas. I was actually thinking more from a performance perspective. i.e. Based on your answer I would assume that you would get better perfomance if you marshalled a large collection of property changes to the dispatcher manually instead of it being done implicitly for everyone.